# C++ decrementing the iterator

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I'm new to C++ and currently learning iterators.

I wrote the following code, which adds the first and last digit in a vector.

In order to decrement the iterator, I've had to decrement the variable `dec_pointer` twice for the correct results. I'm obviously doing something wrong, but what?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec{1,4,2,6,9,10,17,13,15};
    size_t first_last =0;
    size_t dec_pointer  = vec.size()-1;
    
    for(auto it =vec.cbegin(); it !=vec.cend() && !vec.empty(); ++it)
    {
        first_last = *it + *(it+(dec_pointer--));
        std::cout<<"Add First and Last Digit : "<<first_last<<std::endl;
        dec_pointer--;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just use a `for(int i=0; i < vec.size(); ++i)` and skip all the psuedo-pointer nonsense. It'll be faster in *every* case, and you can avoid all the crazy syntax.

Answer (score 2):

If you were adding the first and last elements (as per your text), you wouldn't need a loop, you could just do (after checking minimum size, of course):

```cpp
first_plus_last = *(vec.cbegin()) + *(vec.cend()-1);
```

It *looks* however that you're trying to add the first and last, second and second last, and so on. The reason why you would have to decrement twice is because you're getting the second iterator value by adding something to the *current* iterator value (not the start iterator).

For example, let's for the purposes of understanding just pretend they're *indexes* rather than iterators:

```
index:  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
value:  1  4  2  6  9 10 17 13 15
```

To correctly add the first (moving) index and a delta value to get the second index, you would need:

```
index1  index2  index2 as (index1 + delta)
------  ------  --------------------------
     0       8            0 + 8
     1       7            1 + 6
     2       6            2 + 4
... and so on
```

You can see that the required delta is decreasing by *two* each time: `8, 6, 4, ...`.

---

But, rather than doing iterator calculations, I would opt for just running an iterator from both ends, toward the middle. In other words, something like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec{1, 4, 2, 6, 9, 10, 17, 13, 15};

    if (vec.size() > 0) {
        auto left = vec.cbegin();
        auto right = vec.cend() - 1;
        while (left < right) {
            auto num1 = *left++;
            auto num2 = *right--;
            auto sum = num1 + num2;
            std::cout << "Add (" << num1 << ", " << num2 << "): " << sum << '\n';
        }
        if (left == right) {
            std::cout << "One number left in middle: " << *left << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

That seems like cleaner (as in "easier to understand") code to me, and the output is:

```
Add (1, 15): 16
Add (4, 13): 17
Add (2, 17): 19
Add (6, 10): 16
One number left in middle: 9
```

It also works with all the possible vector sizes (empty, one element, even number of elements, and odd number of elements greater than one).

Comment: Your first example might be clearer as `vec.front() + vec.back()`

Comment: Thank you you've made it much clearer to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you used `vec.cbegin()` instead of `it` when calculating the last pointer, you would not have this issue.

```
first_last = *it + *(vec.cbegin() + dec_pointer--)
```

Answer (score 0):

On the 1st loop iteration, `it` refers to the first element, and `dec_pointer` is 8, so you have:

```
-----------------------------------------
| 1 | 4 | 2 | 6 | 9 | 10 | 17 | 13 | 15 |
-----------------------------------------
  ^                                  ^ 
  it                                it+8
```

If you then increment `it` by 1 and decrement `dec_pointer` by 1 not 2, on the 2nd iteration `dec_pointer` is now `7` and you have this:

```
-----------------------------------------
| 1 | 4 | 2 | 6 | 9 | 10 | 17 | 13 | 15 |
-----------------------------------------
      ^                              ^ 
      it                            it+7
```

If you then increment `it` by 1 and decrement `dec_pointer` by 1 not 2, on the 3rd iteration `dec_pointer` is now `6` and you have this:

```
-----------------------------------------
| 1 | 4 | 2 | 6 | 9 | 10 | 17 | 13 | 15 |
-----------------------------------------
          ^                          ^ 
          it                        it+6
```

And so on.  So, as you can see, the `last` value you refer to with `it+dec_pointer` is always the same element `15`.  That is why you have to decrement `dec_pointer` by 2 instead of 1 to get the correct result:

```
-----------------------------------------
| 1 | 4 | 2 | 6 | 9 | 10 | 17 | 13 | 15 |
-----------------------------------------
  ^   ^   ^                ^    ^    ^ 
  it  |   |                |    |   it+8
      |   |                |    |
     it+1 |                | (it+1)+6
          |                |
         it+2           (it+2)+4
```

That being said, I would suggest an alternative and simpler solution - use a `reverse_iterator` from `vec.crbegin()` to access the 2nd value, instead of offsetting a forward `iterator` from `vec.cbegin()`, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec{1,4,2,6,9,10,17,13,15};
    auto last_it = vec.crbegin();
    
    for(auto it = vec.cbegin(); it != vec.cend(); ++it, ++last_it)
    {
        int first_last = *it + *last_it;
        std::cout << "Add First and Last Digit : " << first_last << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/pHxbsQ)

Or even simpler, just get rid of the `it` loop iterator completely:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec{1,4,2,6,9,10,17,13,15};
    auto last_it = vec.crbegin();

    for(int first : vec)
    {
        int first_last = first + *last_it++;
        std::cout << "Add First and Last Digit : " << first_last << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/IwvzAT)

Comment: Thank you, using crbegin() makes sense.